# Ordenar un arreglo multidimensional con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un arreglo multidimensional y no funciona el código que me dieron como respuesta en otra pregunta, este solo funciona con un arreglo no multidimensional:

```
<?php
$array = Array(
            "Color"           => "YELLOW",
            "Variedad"        => "CHERRY",
            "Grado"           => "NORMAL",
            "Finca"           => "FINCA1",
            "Producto"        => "FLOWER1",
            "year"            => 2016,
            "week"            => 26,
            "quantity"        => 91570,
            "quantity_origin" => 2096
        );

print_r($array);

function my_sort($a,$b){
    $orden = array(   
                "Finca"           => 1, 
                "Producto"        => 2, 
                "Bloque"          => 3,
                "Variedad"        => 4, 
                "Color"           => 5, 
                "Grado"           => 6, 
                "year"            => 7, 
                "week"            => 8, 
                "quantity"        => 9, 
                "quantity_origin" => 10

            );

    return (($orden[$a])) < (($orden[$b])) ? -1 : 1;

}

uksort($array,"my_sort");

print_r($array);
?>
```

No lo quiero ordenar ni alfabéticamente, sino como esta en la función mysort() del código anterior, lo intenté de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
    $array = Array(
                  Array(
                    "Color"           => "YELLOW",
                    "Variedad"        => "CHERRY",
                    "Grado"           => "NORMAL",
                    "Finca"           => "FINCA1",
                    "Producto"        => "FLOWER1",
                    "year"            => 2016,
                    "week"            => 26,
                    "quantity"        => 91570,
                    "quantity_origin" => 2096
                  ),

                 Array(
                    "Color"           => "BLUE",
                    "Variedad"        => "CHERRY",
                    "Grado"           => "GOLD",
                    "Finca"           => "FINCA1",
                    "Producto"        => "FLOWER1",
                    "year"            => 2016,
                    "week"            => 26,
                    "quantity"        => 91570,
                    "quantity_origin" => 2096
                  ),
            );


    print_r($array);

    function my_sort($a,$b){
        $orden = array(
                   array(   
                    "Finca"           => 1, 
                    "Producto"        => 2, 
                    "Bloque"          => 3,
                    "Variedad"        => 4, 
                    "Color"           => 5, 
                    "Grado"           => 6, 
                    "year"            => 7, 
                    "week"            => 8, 
                    "quantity"        => 9, 
                    "quantity_origin" => 10
                   )
                );

        for($i=0; $i < count($orden); $i++){
           $orden = (($orden[$i][$a])) < (($orden[$i][$b])) ? -1 : 1;
        }     
        return $orden;

    }

    uksort($array,"my_sort");

    print_r($array);
    ?>
```

Nota: Uso Phalcon Framework para el código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que que tienes que recorrer con un bucle es el array multidimensional, para aplicarle la ordenación a cada array interior. La función de comparación es un función sencilla a la que se le pasan 2 elementos y devuelve cual es el mayor según el orden.

```
 <?php
        $array = Array(
                      Array(
                        "Color"           => "YELLOW",
                        "Variedad"        => "CHERRY",
                        "Grado"           => "NORMAL",
                        "Finca"           => "FINCA1",
                        "Producto"        => "FLOWER1",
                        "year"            => 2016,
                        "week"            => 26,
                        "quantity"        => 91570,
                        "quantity_origin" => 2096
                      ),

                     Array(
                        "Color"           => "BLUE",
                        "Variedad"        => "CHERRY",
                        "Grado"           => "GOLD",
                        "Finca"           => "FINCA1",
                        "Producto"        => "FLOWER1",
                        "year"            => 2016,
                        "week"            => 26,
                        "quantity"        => 91570,
                        "quantity_origin" => 2096
                      ),
                );


        print_r($array);

        function my_sort($a,$b){
            $orden = array(   
                        "Finca"           => 1, 
                        "Producto"        => 2, 
                        "Bloque"          => 3,
                        "Variedad"        => 4, 
                        "Color"           => 5, 
                        "Grado"           => 6, 
                        "year"            => 7, 
                        "week"            => 8, 
                        "quantity"        => 9, 
                        "quantity_origin" => 10
                    );


            return (($orden[$a])) < (($orden[$b])) ? -1 : 1;

        }

        $res = [];

        foreach ($array as $arrayInterior) {
            uksort($arrayInterior, "my_sort");
            array_push($res, $arrayInterior);
        }

        print_r($res);

        ?>
```

[Ejemplo en PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6491537b80e95ce26573d2e2a8af3bd9480d52eb)

Comment: Muchas gracias me funcionó muy bien, te agradezco Saludo!